# How to display on form and edit collection of roles of user entity [symfony2]?

Tags: select, symfony, collections, roles

I had a 'User' entity which contains one 'Role' entity.

Controller code:

```
/**
     *  @Route("/root/users/edit/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
     *  @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function usersEditAction(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('username', 'text')
            ->add('role', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'Lan\CsmBundle\Entity\Role', 'property' => 'role'))
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $form->submit($request);

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('root_users'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('CsmBundle:Root:users_edit.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
    }
```

This code edits 'User' object with one role and 'Role' object was displayed as 'select' on HTML form.

Now, i have changed scheme of db and 'User' may have many 'Role's. On form it can be displayed as 'select' with multiple attribute. But i don't know a true-way how to do that on symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [Entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) has a [multiple](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple) property. So you can just add it.

Comment: not work, error: Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object.

Comment: define `roles` as ArrayCollection in your entity. Like here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html